# POST req: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

I am writing this app.js client file that performs a post request to a server (code below):

```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');

    /* Function to POST data */
    const postData = async ( url = 'http://localhost/8000/add/', data = {})=>{
          console.log(data)
          const response = await  fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
        });
      
        try {
            const newData = await response.json();
            console.log(newData);
            return newData
        }catch(error) {
          console.log("errors", error);
          // appropriately handle the error
        }
    }



  // TODO-Call Function
  postData('/addAnimal', {animal: 'girrafe'});
```

I keep on getting this error when I run with `node app.js`:

```
node .\app.js
{ animal: 'girrafe' }
D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305
                throw new TypeError('Only absolute URLs are supported');
                      ^

TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305:9)
D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305
                throw new TypeError('Only absolute URLs are supported');
                      ^

TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305:9)
    at D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1410:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1407:9)
    at postData (D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\demo\app.js:22:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Downloads\FEWD\WebAPIs\N&E\demo\app.js:42:3)
```

Any suggestion as to why, would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `url = 'http://localhost/8000/add'` sets the default parameter to that URL, then you overwrite it with `'/addAnimal'` when you provide that as an argument. You should provide an absolute URL:

```js
postData('http://localhost/8000/addAnimal', {animal: 'girrafe'});
```

As a side note, I'm pretty sure `localhost/8000` is a typo and should be `localhost:8000`.